# MAX date problem I've tried two solutions I've found but the results dont match

Tags: row-number, maxdate

I am trying to find the Max date (latest date) for each accountid in my table FilteredVisit. In my table I have the fields: accountid, casereference and visitdate.

I want the latest date for each accountid. Some have multiple visits some only one visit.

I have 2,464 records in the visit table and I know that I have 1,185 unique accounts in that table.

So I'm expecting 1,185 records the result of the query. But having tried the two methods below I get different answers neither of which match the target of 1,185 records.

These are the methods I've tried:

```
Select accountid, casereference, visitdate
from (Select accountid, casereference, visitdate, 
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by visitdate order by accountid) as rn from FilteredVisit) as T
where rn = 1
order by hiw_accountid
```

--which returns 1,215 records

---

```
SELECT  accountid, casereference, visitdate
FROM FilteredVisit S 
WHERE visitdate=(SELECT MAX(visitdate) FROM Filteredhiw_inspection WHERE hiw_accountid = S.hiw_accountid)
ORDER BY accountid
```

-- which returns 1,165 records

which solution do I trust? What have I done wrong? Thanks

It’s a backend db for a CRM. Standard setup as far as I know.
Thanks for the feedback which has helped update this post.

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: It’s a backend db for a CRM. Standard setup as far as I know.

Comment: You are not as clear as you think you are. To improve your question: Do you want the most recent value of `visitdate` for each `accountid` (as I understand from your first sentence, even if it is not stated that clearly)? Or do you want all the fields for the most recent record (evaluated with `visitdate`) of each `accountid` (as suggested by the fact you included the extra `casereference` field in your queries)? Regarding the expected result: you say you have 1185 distinct accounts in the `FilteredVisit` table? Should it not be the number of records you expect? If not, can you explain why?

Comment: @Atmo, yes you are right I havent explained myself clearly enough sorry about that (i'll edit the post). Yes there are 1185 distinct AccountId's, I want the latest date for each accountid some have multiple visits some only one. So I was expecting 1185 as a result of the query and not the two different results I've had. Hence my confusion. Thanks for the feedback/help.

Answer (score 0):

Either you only want the date for each `accountid`, in which case you can do:

```sql
SELECT  accountid, MAX(visitdate)
FROM FilteredVisit
GROUP BY accountid
```

That way, you are guaranteed every `accountid` is returned (guaranteed because there is no filter in a `WHERE` clause) exactly once (guaranteed by the `GROUP BY` clause).

---

If you need all the columns, using a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function is the right approach but you did so incorrectly. You want to partition your records by `accountid` and inside each partition, you want to apply an order by `visitdate` that will let you know which one is the latest.
Window functions, as suggested by the fact they work with a `partition` of your records rather than aggregate them with a `group by`, do not change the number of records returned by the query, compared to the number of records passed to them. For that, you need to add a `WHERE` clause to ensure you only keep records you are interested in.

```sql
SELECT accountid, casereference, visitdate
FROM (
SELECT accountid, casereference, visitdate,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountid ORDER BY visitdate DESC) AS IndexVisitDesc
FROM FilteredVisit
) AS T
WHERE IndexVisitDesc = 1
```

Note that in cases where you anticipate ties within partitions (in the above case, if 2 visits take place at the same `visitdate`), you may need to use the `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` window functions instead or `ROW_NUMBER()`.